# Bootstrap 3 modal: make it movable/draggable without jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm tring to develop some things:

- make a bootstrap modal draggable/movable on the window without jquery-ui

I use backbone.js but I think this is not so important. In a piece of code I define my bootstram modal:

```
<div id="detailsContainer">
<div class="modal fade" id="someId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Some Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="content">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="modalFormBody">
                ... some content
            </form>    

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="pull-right" id="modalButtonBar">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default control-button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary control-button" id="addButton">Add</button>
            </div>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when I try to use set the modal draggable with this code:

```
 var $container = $("#detailsContainer");
 $container.on('mousedown', 'div', function() {
            $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() / 2,
                    left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() / 2
                }).on('mouseup', function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable');
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }).on('mouseup', function() {
            $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');
        });
```

the behaviour is strange:

- when I pick up the modal the modal goes out of window. I tried to fix changing some values to top and left, but nothing has been good.
- when I pick some under element of the modal-body (for example an Input text), then I can move arround in the modal the input text. But I don't want this! I only want that the whole modal can be draggable/movable.

The example above I have found it on stackoverflow (Sorry I don't find the link on it). I find also some example with jquery-ui. But I don't want to use it. Only Jquery.

I have also tried: [Dialog draggable](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/), and [JQuery Draggable Demo](http://tovic.github.io/dte-project/jquery-draggable/index.html). But without success.
The first one don't make my modal draggable, and the second one I din't understand how to use it with *$container*

Can someone help me?

**Update**

```
        $('body').on('mousedown', '.modal-dialog', function() {
             $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) {
                 $('.draggable').offset({
                     top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() / 2,
                     left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() / 2
                 }).on('mouseup', function() {
                     $(this).removeClass('draggable');
                 });
             });
             e.preventDefault();
         }).on('mouseup', function() {
             $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');
         });
```

But when I want to drag... it changes the position of where I picked it up the modal. It goes on the corner. Not there where I picked it up? How can I correct this? It's wrong to put the ".modal-dialog" on the mousedown function? And If this is wrong, which element I have to put it there?

And an other point: the elements that I have in the modal body (example drop down) must not be draggable. How can I exclude them?

Comment: check this fiddle without jquery ui https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/mkUJf/

Comment: This solutions is more similar to what I expect. Now they are only two things, that I added in the update.

Comment: I'm not very happy with that. When you press to meve the modal, it disappear on the window... how can I correct that? And how can I exclude the behavior on the input text (input and textarea)?

Comment: now check my updated answer it's solved just change this top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() /8, left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() /8 and updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mkUJf/1452/

Comment: Ok, it's not the best UI feeling ... but at the moment it is the best solution I have. Tank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code surely it'll helps you, below code is without jquery ui

check this updated fiddle [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/mkUJf/1452/)

```js
$(function() {
    $('body').on('mousedown', '#myModal', function(ev) {
        $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() /8,
                left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() /8
            }).on('mouseup', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            });
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');
    });
});
```

```css
body {padding:50px;}

div {
  cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First: tank you for you're help. This solution for me gives an error  $(...).resizable is not a function becouse I don't include jquery-ui. The fidle in the comment are more that what I'm looking for.

Comment: this solution's problem is that, wherever i click on the modal, the modal will move so that the mouse pointer is returned to top left corner. I want the mouse pointer keep the same position as I clicked. Is there any solution for this problem, are you guy still working on this?

Comment: The demo works bad. When I start to move the dialog, an ugly effect is produced (the dialog moves some pixels to the right, but only when the dialog starts to be moved)

Comment: @jstuardo can you share your snippet here

Comment: @UdhayTitus Not own snippet but yours. Just click on "Run code snippet" button.  Then click on "Launch demo modal". When modal appears, move the mouse until the move cursor is displayed. Then left-click, and finally move the dialog. You will notice the dialog jumps to the right before starting moving. I tested in Chrome and in Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is too late, but in case someone (like me) was searching for a solution to this. Finally, my solution was to use this code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.drags = function (opt) {

        opt = $.extend({ handle: "", cursor: "move" }, opt);

        var $el = null;
        if (opt.handle === "") {
            $el = this;
        } else {
            $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }

        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function (e) {
            var $drag = null;
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                $drag = $(this).parents('.modal-dialog').addClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $drag = $(this).parents('.modal-dialog').addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function (e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top: e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left: e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                }).on("mouseup", function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
        }).on("mouseup", function () {
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
            }
        });

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then, when the modal is shown:

```
            $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).find('.card-header').drags();
            });

            $('#modal').modal({ show: true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
```

I am using a card inside the modal dialog with an HTML like this:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content  animated bounceInRight">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header border-bottom-0">My super title</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form >...</form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAlmacenar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Almacenar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the whole snippet if you want to try it:

```js
(function ($) {
        $.fn.drags = function (opt) {
    
            opt = $.extend({ handle: "", cursor: "move" }, opt);
    
            var $el = null;
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                $el = this;
            } else {
                $el = this.find(opt.handle);
            }
    
            return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function (e) {
                var $drag = null;
                if (opt.handle === "") {
                    $drag = $(this).parents('.modal-dialog').addClass('draggable');
                } else {
                    $drag = $(this).parents('.modal-dialog').addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
                }
                var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                    drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                    drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                    pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                    pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
                $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function (e) {
                    $('.draggable').offset({
                        top: e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                        left: e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                    }).on("mouseup", function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                    });
                });
                e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
            }).on("mouseup", function () {
                if (opt.handle === "") {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
                }
            });
    
        }
    })(jQuery);
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $(this).find('.card-header').drags();
                });

                $('#modal').modal({ show: true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content  animated bounceInRight">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header border-bottom-0">My super title</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form></form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAlmacenar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Almacenar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is nice how it handles the offset of the mouse down! no jump in the drag element. This appears to use this code https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/